# Yelp V2 API INVALID_SIGNATURE Error in response in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, yelp

I am using yelp V2 API in my app. Till now I was getting proper response(result) from yelp, but now I am getting below response for same request using same API key. I requesting for restaurant and food detail in any particular area.

---

my request :

http://api.yelp.com/v2/search?term=mcdonalds&location=la&category_filter=restaurants,food

yelp response :

```
error =     {
description = "Invalid signature. Expected signature base string: GET&http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fv2%2Fsearch&category_filter%3Drestaurants%252Cfood%26location%3Dla%26oauth_consumer_key%3DQcDLfDCmeSlI**********%26oauth_nonce%3DAC37FDC4-11A1-40EA-AD66-B402E7D54EFD%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1317792252%26oauth_token%3DRYQ0HAfm0oQMqcASn5QDofj23ipsoH1-%26oauth_version%3D1.0%26term%3Dmcdonalds";

id = "INVALID_SIGNATURE";

text = "Signature was invalid";
    };
```

---

I am not getting what is the problem exactly. So please help me for the same...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is is strange that the (URL-decoded) string is 

http://localhost ??

Answer (score 2):

Actually this was the problem from yelp. Now they have solved the problem, so its working fine now.